# List only text files in directory and edit each text file

Tags: php, post

I need to be able to list all text files that are in a directory, then be able to edit each individual text file. Each text file is only one line (50 characters). The code below will list the text files and also an image too. I just need to edit the text file only.

```
foreach (glob("thumb/*.{txt}",GLOB_BRACE) as $filetxt) {
    $desc = file_get_contents($filetxt);
    $pics = $filetxt;
    $pic = str_replace('_alt.txt', '', $pics);

//echo $desc;   
echo '<img style="margin:0 20px 7px;" src="'.$pic.'" /><br /><input type="radio"     name="radioid" id="'.$filetxt.'" value="'.$filetxt.'" /><input type="text" name="editit"     id="'.$filetxt.'" maxlength="50" style="width:400px; height: 20px;" value="'.$desc.'"     /><br /><br />';
}
if(isset($_POST['doedit'])){
$line=0;
$newdata=$_POST['editit'];
$datams[$line]=$newdata."\r\n";
$datams=implode($datams);
file_put_contents($filetxt,($datams));
}
```

Comment: The number of answers (0) could indicate that your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need `<form>` and `<button>`

```
<form method="POST">

    <img ... /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="radioid" ... />
    <input type="text" name="editit" ... /><br />
    <br />

    <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Server send page to you. You make modyfication and press `SEND`. Information goes to server. Server see `$_POST['doedit']` and save information to file, and send to you the same page again.

But you have many lines with `<input>` and all `<input>` need uniq `name` (not `id`) or the same name but with `[]` `<input name='editit[]' ... >` to get `$_POST['doedit'][0]`,  `$_POST['doedit'][1]` etc. and `$_POST['editit'][0]`, `$_POST['editit'][1]` etc.

Comment: The images and text files are already on server. This is to edit the existing text files. The text files only list the title for the image.

Comment: It's hard to explain all here in few words.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is not quite clear. Do you have a form element somewhere in your file as furas pointed. Are you able to submit the form? And lastly, are you getting any errors?

In addition to that, looking at your code, the `$filetxt` variable on line 14 is out of scope in this case as the second block of code where you save the content is outside the foreach loop. I presume that it is supposed to have the name of the file selected by the radio button?

In this case, you have to get the POST value of the selected radio button "radioid" which contains the name of the file where the data will be saved.

This is how it is supposed to be:

```
  ...
    $filetxt = $_POST['radioid'];
    file_put_contents($filetxt,($datams));
  }
```

The above is just part of the problem, you still have to resolve the duplicate name issue as furas pointed.